# While talking about a program, use `run` or `execute`?

Tags: word-choice

`run` and `execute` have similar meaning when talking about a program, like we can say

> run this program

or

> execute your program

, but I'm not sure if they are the same.

Comment: Basically the same, though some context would be helpful. *run* refers to operation, while *execute* (in computing) refers to operations being performed on computer code. It depends on where you are looking from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are the same.

One difference is, it's (in my experience) much less common to see *execute* used intransitively than it is to see *run* used intransitively.

So

> The program is running

is fairly common, but

> (*) The program is executing

is fairly rare (and would probably come across as simply wrong to some people).